# Accesing parent identifier in an ordered nested subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need a query to get the value of an item together with the value of the previous item if exists.

I am using the following query (a simplification of the actual):

```
select v1.value item_value,
nvl(
  (
    select * from (
      select v2.value
      from ITEMS v2
      where v2.insert_date<v1.insert_date
      order by v2.insert_date desc
    ) where rownum=1
  ), 0
) as previous_value
from ITEMS v1
where v1.item_id=1234
```

This query won't work (ORA-00904) because I am using `v1.insert_date` in an inner select with two levels of nesting.

How can I achieve this with Oracle 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve this with analytic function LAG. More info about analytic functions [LAG LEAD](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php)

I created a sample query:

```
with items as (
select 1 as value, sysdate as insert_date from dual
union all 
select 2 as value, sysdate-1 as insert_date from dual
union all
select 3 as value, sysdate+1 as insert_date from dual
)

select v1.value item_value,
lag(v1.value,1,0) over (order by v1.insert_date desc) as previous_value,insert_date
from ITEMS v1
order by insert_date desc
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll upvote because for using LAG, but in my case I need  to query by ID. If I  use `where v1.item_id=1234` LAG won't work because there is only one result.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired result set?

Comment: In you example, the row with `item_value=1` has a `previous_value=3`. If you add `where v1.value=1` `previous_value` is now `0`when I'm expecting `3`

Comment: So nest Stefan's query into another query in this way: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/92